# Retrieve max date only when duplicate

Tags: oracle, count, max

i need help retrieving data from the following schema:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e532ff/1

I need to retrieve only the max(arrive_date) if the max(arive_date) is duplicate for the id_item.

Using MySql from sqlfiddle the query returns what i want, homewever when using Oracle 11g its not returning what i need. The problem seems to be when i add the count(*) clause.

Anyone have any idea on why its not working?

Answer (score 1):

You are using:

```
select id_item,max(date(arrive_date))
from itens
group by id_item,arrive_date
having count(*)>1;
```

Try below Query: (I have removed the arrive_date from the group by clause)

```
select id_item,max(date(arrive_date))
itens
group by id_item
having count(*)>1;
```

**Result of above query:**

```
ID_ITEM |  MAX(DATE(ARRIVE_DATE))
19604   |  2029-06-13
24498   |  2009-10-09
```

In case you want all 3 records, then use: (Remove the having clause)

```
select id_item,max(date(arrive_date))
itens
group by id_item;
```

**Result of above query:**

```
ID_ITEM |  MAX(DATE(ARRIVE_DATE))
19604   |  2029-06-13
24498   |  2009-10-09
32213   |  2009-10-09
```

By the way, for **Oracle**, try using trunc function instead of date function like, **max(trunc(arrive_date))**

Comment: Thanks Nisha, i tried the following query in Oracle:
select id_item,max(date(arrive_date))
itens
group by id_item
having count(*)>1;

It seems right to me as you wrote and it should work. Homewerver when i add count(*)>1 it retrieves all the dates regardless if its the max_date or not. I wonder if theres something to do with permissions on my user.
Very frustrating i dont know what else i could be doing wrong. :(